# I can't update flutter plugin from 47.0.2 to 47.0.3 over. (Android Studio in Mac)

Tags: flutter

I wanna solve that Flutter Device Selection stack with loading.
This problem fixed Flutter plugin ver 47.0.3 over, but i cant update.
Plugins marketplace display 47.0.2 only.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3892

New versions didnt release Android Studio in Mac OS ?
There is new versions in official page...

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions

Configuration:

Android Studio 4.0
macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: You should share your attempts here to help us better understand what error/conflict occurred so we can give you better answers

Comment: I reinstalled Android Studio and Flutter SDK, it has no effect. I downloaded version 47.0.3 
from official page and replaced with ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio4.0/flutter-intellij. It shows "Incompatible  with the current Android Studio Version".

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by downgrade flutter.